# How to prevent nginx reverse proxy recompress the upstream compressed response?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ngx-brotli

I have nginx reverse proxy that receives brotli compressed response from upstream (Varnish cache). But, the reverse proxy serves brotli compressed response to browser only if I setup "brotli on;" within the reverse proxy server block.

My goal is to have the nginx reverse proxy not handle compression at all. To achieve this, I have following questions:

1. Is the reverse proxy block expected to un-compress the received response and handle it on it's own? Can't it directly pass the upstream response back to client?
2. Is there a way to dump proxy response or it's size to nginx logs? This shall help debug the issue better.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but could this be fixed by a simple `gzip off;` in your nginx config?

Comment: Tried `gzip off;` and still see the issue. Also, I'm able to reproduce the exact same behavior with gzip (no brotli anywhere). This means, I see uncompressed response to browser even if upstream returns gzipped response but gzip is off on nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved this so posting this for anyone who may encounter similar issue:

1. Varnish changed my 'Accept-Encoding' request header to 'gzip'. According to Varnish documentation, this is as designed ([see here](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/compression.html)).
2. However, the upstream nginx server (behind varnish) responded with non-compressed content because the default for `gzip_http_version` is 1.0 while the default for `proxy_http_version` is 1.1. ([see here](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2015/11/19/nginx-proxy-gzip.html))

Resolution was achieved by:

a. setting Varnish to not worry about compression by passing `-p http_gzip_support=off` to `varnishd`.

b. setting `gzip_http_version` to `1.1` on the upstream Nginx server.

Deciphering the above behavior became possible because I logged the following on my upstream nginx server (the one behind varnish):

```
log_format bytes_sent '$bytes_sent' - '$http_accept_encoding' - '$request';
```